# Using Quickly to develop apps for Raspberry Pi?

Tags: application-development, python, quickly

Can Raspberry Pi apps be developed with Quickly on Ubuntu? I know there isn't Ubuntu for the Pi yet but what I want to do is develop the app on my Ubuntu machine, compile it and copy the deb file to the Pi. Then install and run it. Will this work? It will be much easier to make the apps I need to make to with Quickly. I assume I will have to use something other than ubuntu-application when creating the app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Quickly, nor do I know much about Raspberry Pi, but for what it's worth...

Quickly is set up to configure packages to be installed into /opt/ubuntu.extras/appname (or something similar). That is probably the main difference from anything else, since this is not standard in any other linux flavor.

This should not keep you from using Quickly to develop apps for Raspberry Pi, or any device using Fedora or Windows or whatever else operating system. You just need to modify the code snippets that define installation folders and make them use something more generic like for example `home = os.path.expanduser('~')` or `os.environ['HOME']` for configuration files and then something for location of application scripts.

Comment: Actually, by default quickly does NOT put packages in /opt/extras.ubuntu.com.  That only occurs if you do `quickly submitubuntu`